# Need Help converting curl to google script code

Tags: curl, google-apps-script

I've been trying to convert the following line of curl code to Google Apps Script and have had no luck.

The curl code:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.textspaced.com/market/commodities/" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "token=###"
```

I've tried different styles of headers and different ways of labeling the token and payloads, but I always get the error that No API token has been provided.

Google Apps Script code:

```
function preshfinder() {
  var message = 'token=###' ; 
  var payloads = JSON.stringify(message);  
  var headers =  {'accept': 'application/json',
                              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                            };
  var requestOptions = {    
             "ContentType" : "application/json",
             headers: headers,
             method: "POST",
             payload:  payloads, 
              followRedirects : true,
            };

            var fetcher = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.textspaced.com/market/commodities', requestOptions)
             Logger.log(fetcher.getContentText());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- You want to convert the following curl command to Google Apps Script.

  ```
  curl -X POST \
  "https://api.textspaced.com/market/commodities/" \
  -H "accept: application/json" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  -d "token=###"
  ```
- You have already confirmed that the above curl command worked.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- In your curl command, the content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. And the data is sent as form.
- The default value of `followRedirects` is `true`.

When above points are reflected to your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function preshfinder() {
  var payloads = {token: "###"};  // Please set your token here.
  var headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json'
  };
  var requestOptions = {
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    headers: headers,
    method: "POST",
    payload:  payloads,
  };
  var fetcher = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.textspaced.com/market/commodities', requestOptions)
  Logger.log(fetcher.getContentText());
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

The request of above modified script is the same with the curl command. But I cannot test this. So if this didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.